# (WF) workflow design patterns .net 3.0

Tags: .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

I have some workflow to work with in Worflow foundation. I need to follow some workflow design patterns

Some best performances in workflow

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can practice you implementation according to your need.

http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/465.aspx